# Facebook JS connect unsupported browser

Tags: iphone, facebook, google-chrome

I am trying to do a JavaScript login from my iPhone 4 running Chrome for iOS version 26.0.1410.53 but I'm getting an error as seen below.

**Here's the live URL to replicate on iPhone** - http://mni.me/master

1. Click on "Get your own homepage like this"
2. Click on "Login with Facebook"

**Here's my JavaScript**

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r) {
        if (r.status !== 'connected') {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("User alredy connected with FB app. Checking if user is in DB");
            var url = 'api/isUser.php?fid='+r.authResponse.userID;
            isUser(url);
        }
    });
```

**It's working fine on Chrome for Desktop, but I'm getting this error on iPhone...**
[image]

**What is the problem and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

It's been around since Chrome 19.

Check here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325086340912814/ for more details.

I'm not sure if there will be a workaround or fix soon.This issue was logged about 10 months ago.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136610

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for awhile.

This may not be a perfect solution but I was able to get around this by getting the login url using the PHP SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) and linking that to the Facebook button. It works on Chrome mobile.

I'm not sure if there's an equivalent to the getLoginUrl for the JS SDK.